How can I display the DateTimeField in the django template as it's display in the admin when I create a view?
This is my model:
 class Event(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
  club = models.CharField(max_length=70)
  event_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="event_images", default='aqsa_copy.jpeg', blank=True)
  date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

This is how it displayed in the admin:

I want to make it like this at the template, and be able to pick a date and time.
But what I got for now is that:

Please help me if you can?

Post your template, form, and other relevant information.

You can archive those things using widgets functionality of django model form
form.py
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'club', 'date', 'location', 'first_name']
        widgets = {
            
            'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
        }

# Html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{form}}
</body>
</html>

Final Output

